# How to limit changes on a mesh according to axis in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I deformed a grid mesh in the shape of a curve using the set position node. Now I want to limit the deformation only to the part of the mesh that is on the left of the y-axis. That is, only the vertices that have negative x values. The rest of the grid should remain a normal plane. I tried using the minimum, maximum, greater-than, and less-than math nodes but it does not really have the effect I want. I think I'm not placing them correctly in the node tree. Kindly assist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to affect only those parts of the grid that have negative X values, you have to use *Selection* in the *Set Position* node.

The criterion has to be X < 0. Since you already have a *Separate XYZ* node you can simply plug a *Less Than* math node after the X output and plug the result into the *Selection* input.

[image: gn selection]

Comment: Thank yo, Gordon. Exactly what I need!

Comment: @EdwardSerfontein You're welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer then? ;)